# Save HBITMAP as PNG image using GDI?

Tags: c, winapi, png, gdi

I'm looking to save an HBITMAP to a PNG image. Is this possible using only the GDI API? (I'm using C, so no GDI+.)  I have only found examples like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to save to a BMP file. Or should I use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) and use [GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567875/how-would-i-load-a-png-image-using-win32-gdi-no-gdi-if-possible) (about reading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, GDI does not support PNGs.

Comment: Okay, so is using GetDIBits to provide data to libpng the typical way to go here?

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Windows API does not expose *any* c++ classes directly from DLLs - The c++ standard does not define an ABI, and as such, the calling conventions and name mangling's used are left to specific implementations to define.

As such, up until Metro at least, all "C++" interfaces supported by the Windows OS have actually been a regular dll exporting a C compatible API, and an accompyining set of c++ header files with the necessary template and inline code.

As such, GDI+ has a [Flat API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documented in MSDN.

Comment: Is this answer to this or some other question?

Comment: The point is, requiring a C compatible API does not exclude GDI+.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I just assumed they were actually exporting the classes. However I think libpng will be far less painful than trying to get the Flat API calls right :-)