# Loading png-file from resources (without MFC, ATL)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, gdi+, gdi

I want to load PNG-file from resources. There is a roughly MFC-way (with [CResourceStream](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/vcgeneral/thread/b958bfbd-5aee-4ff1-9088-53c8da0f0eb3)):

```
CImage img;
CResourceStream str(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), _T("PNG"));
img.Load(&str);
CBitmap *bmp(CBitmap::FromHandle(img.operator HBITMAP());
```

But a project is MFC-less and ATL-less. How to write to load png in nonMFC style? As I understand it, this purpose can be achieved by GDI+

***EDIT:*** There is an appropriate [implementation](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/09/displaying_a_splash_screen_with_c_part_i.html) of loading `png` to stream from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568205/148405)

Comment: you can try libpng: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm or this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, GDI+ can easily create an HBITMAP from PNG data in an IStream or file, but going from a resource to an IStream takes some work.

If you call CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &stm), where stm is an IStream* variable, it will basically give you a temporary in-memory stream. You can use FindResource, LoadResource, LockResource, and SizeofResource to get a pointer to your resource data and its size. Once you have both of those things, you can use IStream::Write to copy the data from your resource into the IStream.

Once you have an IStream with your PNG data, pass the IStream to the GDI+ [Bitmap constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and use the [GetHBITMAP method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an HBITMAP.

Comment: @VincentProvirk How to write resource data from from resource pointer to istream ?